# Permutation for equation solving

Tags: combinatorics

If there is an equation `3a + 6b +7d = 55` and the solution set is `{1,4,6}` but it is unknown which number in the solution corresponds to which variable, is there a way to determine which number corresponds with which variable **without** using brute force? Could this method scale if the equation had 1000 variables? Thanks!

Comment: If all coefficients and solutions are non-negative (or conversely, non-positive), then a slightly faster approach than naïve brute force would be to eliminate those coefficient-solution pairs that result in a term greater than the expected sum...

Comment: Ok thanks. Are there any heuristic algorithms or gradient descent methods to try?

Comment: You might want to post the question on the Stack Exchange site for [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/).  It might be a better fit for those communities than for Stack Overflow.

Comment: But regarding the question, do you have any other information that you could leverage to help a develop some heuristic for your unique case?  E.g. Where / how the solution set was obtained?  Why the solution set is in the correct order?  Other relationships between the variables?

Comment: The solution set would only be in the correct order if the equation was true when the solutions where plugged in.

Comment: correct -> incorrect.  I mistyped

Answer (score 0):

This is brute-force solution with pruning search where solution can't be found.

Let's show two things. First, if coefficients and solutions are non-negative numbers and if they are represented as a sorted list, then maximal value equation can have is 'parallel sum', and minimal value is 'reversed sum'.

```
max = sum(c*s for c, s in zip(coeffs, sols))
min = sum(c*s for c, s in zip(coeffs, reversed(sols)))
```

It is enough to see that for four numbers `0 <= a1 <= a2` and `0 <= b1 <= b2` holds:

```
a1*b1 + a2*b2 = a1*b2 + a2*b1 + (a2-a1)*(b2-b1) >= a1*b2 + a2*b1.
```

Second is that it is always possible to transform problem to problem of the same type with non-negative coefficients and solutions. To 'move' solutions to non-negative it is needed to add to all solutions value `-min(solutions)` and to result `-min(solutions)*sum(coefficients)`.
Similar procedure 'moves' coefficients to non-negative.

Here is python implementation of solution:

```
def C(coeffs, res, sols):
    _max = sum(i*j for i, j in zip(coeffs, sols))
    if _max < res:   # No result
        return None
    if _max == res:  # Result mapping coeffs <-> sols
        return sols
    _min = sum(i*j for i, j in zip(coeffs, reversed(sols)))
    if _min > res:   # No result
        return None
    if _min == res:  # Result mapping coeffs <-> reversed sols
        return sols[::-1]  # reverse sols
    # For next coefficient try all solutions
    for i, s in enumerate(sols):
        r = C(coeffs[1:], res - coeffs[0]*s, sols[:i] + sols[(i+1):])
        if r is not None:
            return [s] + r

print C([3, 6, 7], 55, [1, 4, 6])
```